# User-controlled widgets to choose style logic in QGIS

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis-cloud

On my map, I have several rules-based styles for polygons depending on what data a user might want to look at (e.g., raw money spent per geographic boundary vs. money spent per 100,000 people per geographic boundary).

Right now I'm using QGIS Cloud to host the maps for public consumption, and from the looks of it there's no layer style select there, (which would make this infinitely easier).

The solution I came up with was to nest rules-based styles and have that be the only user-controlled piece on the published map. That is, the user could, for example choose from:

1. Total money spent
2. Money spent per 100,000 people
3. Total consumers
4. Consumers per 100,000 people

Once selected, such as from a list box or combo box, the stored variable would change and with it, the rules-based style embedded in the map.

Really three questions here:

First, is this possible? I remember similar in ESRI's Dashboards, but I'd be doing this entirely within QGIS and QGIS Cloud web app. If not, then I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Second, would doing this (once set up) be similar to existing rules-based styles?

Third, is there documentation specific to this that somebody can point me to, if so? As I mentioned I'm getting swamped in all the outdated and non-relevant docs looking for the answer.